What Can I Do to Fix Extreme Lag in Minecraft Bedrock Edition on High-End Windows 11 PC?
I’m experiencing severe lag with Minecraft Bedrock Edition, even though my hardware is high-end. The game feels like it's running at around 5 FPS, even in the main menu. Here’s what I’ve tried so far:

Updated Graphics Drivers: All drivers are up-to-date.
Reinstalled Minecraft: Multiple times.
Adjusted Graphics Settings: Set to the lowest possible.
Checked GPU Usage: Ensured the dedicated GPU is being used.
Updated OS and BIOS: OS and BIOS are up-to-date.
Verified Background Services: Checked for necessary background
services and applications.

I’ve consulted various forums, including Minecraft & Microsoft support and other Q&A sites, without success.
Here are my system details:

Operating System: Windows 11 Pro (Version 23H2 OS Build 22631.4112)
Motherboard: ASUS ROG STRIX B760-A GAMING WIFI D4
Processor: Intel Core i7-13700KF
RAM: 32 GB (3,600 MHz)
Graphics Card: NVIDIA GeForce RTX 4070 12 GB

I’ve created a YouTube video that shows the problem in action, including how the game lags and my system specifications. You can view the video here: 


What else can I do to resolve this issue? Any additional suggestions or diagnostic tools would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you in advance for your help!

I’m not using any mods. I’ve also ensured that Minecraft is set to use my NVIDIA GPU by following the steps in the NVIDIA Control Panel and Windows Graphics Settings. Despite these measures, the game still experiences severe lag.

What's Task Manager say about resource usage?
